# Обновление значений модели pydantic по словарю

Tags: python, pydantic

Как это ни странно, но не могу найти никакого метода модели пакета pydantic, отвечающего за обновление значений объекта по словарю. Странно, что такое возможно при инициализации объекта, но не при его существовании.

Хочется чего-то подобного:

```py
class Foo(BaseModel):
    num: int
    line: str

f = Foo(num=1, line="bla-bla")
f.update({"num": 3})
print(f.dict())        # {"num": 3, "line": "bla-bla"}
```

Я нашел нечто подобное в методе `model.copy(update=dict)`, но оно умеет только создавать копии с изменением данных. Так же есть метод `parse_obj(dict)`, который является классовым и тоже используется исключительно для инициализации.

Есть ли что-то подобное в штатном функционале моделей pydantic?

Comment: Чем не устраивает обновление с созданием копии?

Comment: @insolor тем, что мне не нужна копия. Мне нужно обновить значения в том же экземпляре

Comment: Судя по всему, подобного метода в самом pydantic нет. Возможно есть какие-то сторонние библиотеки. В принципе, решается одним циклом for.